# Hadamard gate as a product of $R_x$, $R_z$ and a phase

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

I am having problems with this task.

Since the Hadamard gate rotates a state $180°$ about the $\hat{n} = \frac{\hat{x} + \hat{z}}{\sqrt{2}}$ axis, I imagine the solution can be found the following way:

First rotate $\hat{n}$ so it lies in the $z$-$y$ plane:
$$R_z(\pi/2)$$
Then rotate $\hat{n}$ so it is parallell with the $z$-axis:
$$R_x(\pi/4)$$
Now do the desired rotation about the $z$-axis:
$$R_z(\pi)$$
Then rotate $\hat{n}$ back to its original position.
The Hadamard gate can then be written:
$$H = e^{i\lambda}R_z(-\pi/2)R_x(-\pi/4) R_z(\pi) R_x(\pi/4) R_z(\pi/2) $$
However, this doesn't seem to work. Can someone explain where my logic is flawed? Thank you very much

Comment: Check exercise 4.4 of [this PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://people.math.gatech.edu/~jeanbel/4782/Year09/problem207.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi_wsanuYbgAhULhuAKHfeTDN4QFjAGegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw1-oAkWqk882BVVuqJcBYys&cshid=1548334205310). It should explain your concern.

Comment: I think you are right but maybe when doing your calculations, you are not dividing by 2 the angles in the rotation matrix definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you say that it doesn't work? If I enter the following code into Mathematica, it works fine:

```
X = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
Z = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};
FullSimplify[-I MatrixExp[-I Pi Z/4].MatrixExp[-I Pi X/8].MatrixExp[I Pi Z/2].MatrixExp[I Pi X/8].MatrixExp[I Pi Z/4]]
```

The only thing that I had to remember was to halve the angles compared to how you wrote them (because $R_Z(\pi)$ should give a $Z$ rotation, which is $e^{i\pi Z/2}$). That's the place that I always make the mistake with these calculations...

Comment: Thank you very much! Not sure where my mistake was, but I wrote down the matrices in wolframalpha. With python it worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, it works fine. If I use the channel-state duality to view this sequence of operation's effect in Quirk's output display, it's the Hadamard gate's matrix:

[image: It's a Hadamard]

Maybe you're multiplying or dividing by 2 somewhere you shouldn't be, when performing the operations?

Comment: I am sure thats what i did wrong! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Check exercise 4.4 of [this PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://people.math.gatech.edu/~jeanbel/4782/Year09/problem207.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi_wsanuYbgAhULhuAKHfeTDN4QFjAGegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw1-oAkWqk882BVVuqJcBYys&cshid=1548334205310). It should explain your concern.

I think you are right but maybe when doing your calculations, you are not dividing by 2 the angles in the rotation matrix definition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have looked at that solution. Even though it solves the problem, it doesnt explain why my logic is flawed