# How to visualize Hadamard gate as $X$-$Z$-$X$ decomposition?

Tags: quantum-gate, nielsen-and-chuang, gate-synthesis, quantum-circuit, hadamard

In the book [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://michaelnielsen.org/qcqi/) by Nielsen and Chuang, chapter 4, exercise 4.4 (pg. 175), the author has asked to express Hadamard gate as product of $R_x$, $R_z$ rotations and $e^{i\phi}$ for some angle $\phi$. I have found two answers for the same.

1. Rotating the Hadamard gate parallel to $|0\rangle$ performing the rotation about $Z$ axis and reverting back to original position. Elaborate mathematical visualisation can be found in the question asked [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5261/hadamard-gate-as-a-product-of-r-x-r-z-and-a-phase). Rewriting rotations as:
   \begin{array}
   \
   &= e^{i\pi/2}R_z(-\pi/2)R_x(-\pi/4)R_z(\pi)R_x(\pi/4)R_z(\pi/2) \\
   &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1\\ 
   1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\\
   &=H
   \end{array}
   I have understood this decomposition very well. Though, its cumbersome to arrive write this decomposition. This led me to the second option.
2. The other way is analytically explained in this [pdf](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Ejeanbel/4782/Year09/problem207.pdf). This yields $X$-$Z$-$X$ decomposition as:
   \begin{array}
   \
   &= e^{i\pi/2}R_x(\pi/2)R_z(\pi/2)R_x(\pi/2) \\
   &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1\\ 
   1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\\
   &=H
   \end{array}

Now, how should I visualize, or intuitively arrive at this second decomposition?

The only way that comes to my mind is to transform $|0\rangle$ and $\frac{|0\rangle + i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ around rotation vector of Hadamard gate under $X$-$Z$-$X$ transformation as discussed in point 1 ([here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17529/13414)). Are there better visualizations possible?

[First edit]

By visualization, I mean, the mental shortcut to decompose Hadamard gate into $R_x(\beta)R_z(\gamma)R_x(\rho)$, without doing the complete matrix multiplication, like,just knowing the Bloch angles made by the axis of rotation of Hadamard gate I can decompose it as $R_z(-\pi/2)R_x(-\pi/4)R_z(\pi)R_x(\pi/4)R_z(\pi/2)$ without bothering to multiply five $2X2$ matrices.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the other answer, the Hadamard gate is a pi rotation (180 degree) around the $X + Z$ axis. That is, it is a 180 degree rotation around the purple axis indicated in the below figure:

[image]

And the $Rx(\pi/2)$ follows by a $Rz(\pi/2)$ then follow by $Rx(\pi/2)$ does exactly this rotation as well.

---

To have better visualization of this, suppose I start my qubit in the state $|0\rangle$ and I apply some rotation $U$ to it. Here, let's take $U$ to be:
$U = \begin{pmatrix}
0.11833 - 0.52719i & 0.18429 - 0.82104i  \\
 -0.18429 - 0.82104i & 0.11833 + 0.52719i  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

Which can be written as $U = R_Y(-2)R_Z(2.7)$. So **we first** apply $R_Y(-2)$ follow by $R_Z(2.7)$ then finally apply the **Hadamard** gate.

[image]

The reason to apply this $U$ is so that we get to a state that is non-trivial so we have better visualization of the rotation. In the animate below, the first two rotations correspond to the $R_Y(-2)$ then $R_Z(2.7)$. The last rotation correspond to the Hadamard rotation.

[image]

**Keep an eye on the last rotation (Hadamard)** as we will compare this to the rotation $Rx(\pi/2)$ follows by a $Rz(\pi/2)$ then follow by $Rx(\pi/2)$ next.

---

Here, we will consider the same starting point. That is, we again map start at the state $|0\rangle$ then apply $U = R_Y(-2)R_Z(2.7)$. But instead of applying the Hadamard gate, we will apply the rotations $Rx(\pi/2)Rz(\pi/2)Rx(\pi/2)$. That is,

[image]

So **watch the last three rotations** carefully. You can see that it reaches to the same final point as previously.

[image]

---

Side to side comparison:

[image]

Comment: I guess the question is misunderstood. Let me reiterate my point using your example. Consider the arbitrary unitary vector $U$ chosen by you. If one knows the axis about which it is causing the rotation, then, I can easily decompose $U$  as $R_z(-\lambda)R_x(-\phi)R_z(\theta)R_z(\lambda)R_x(\phi)$ without doing the matrix multiplication. But, If I have to find $(\beta,\gamma,\rho)$ such that $R_x(\beta)R_z(\gamma)R_z(\rho)=U$, then, I don't have any clue. Basically, how to solve $U=R_x(\beta)R_z(\gamma)R_z(\rho)$, without the heavy matrix multiplication (it a complex matrix)?

Comment: What function should I use to do the same animation?

Comment: HI @narip, I think I used qiskit visualization for this one.

Answer (score 5):

Any gate in the circuit can be seen as an element of SU(2), ignoring the global phase. Hence Hadamard gate can be changed into
$$\sqrt{1/2}\begin{pmatrix}
i & i\\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}.$$
And any element of SU(2) $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
-b^* & a^*
\end{pmatrix}$can be changed into SO(3) with the formula below, which you can find it in some books about group theory:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2}\left(a^{2}+a^{* 2}-b^{2}-b^{* 2}\right) & -\frac{i}{2}\left(a^{2}-a^{* 2}+b^{2}-b^{* 2}\right) & -\left(a b+a^{*} b^{*}\right) \\
\frac{i}{2}\left(a^{2}-a^{* 2}-b^{2}+b^{* 2}\right) & \frac{1}{2}\left(a^{2}+a^{* 2}+b^{2}+b^{* 2}\right) & i\left(a^{*} b^{*}-b a\right) \\
a^{*} b+b^{*} a & i\left(a^{*} b-b^{*} a\right) & a a^{*}-b b^{*}
\end{array}\right)
.$$
Therefore, the corresponding SO(3) element of Hadamard gate can be calculated to be $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. And the rotation axis can be calculated by solving the eigenvector problem, and the proper rotation axis should have the eigenvalue 1 instead of -1. So the final rotation axis is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt2\\
0\\
1/\sqrt2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Conclusion: it's a $\pi$ rotation around $\begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt2\\
0\\
1/\sqrt2
\end{pmatrix}$ axis.  To check the correctness of it, $| 0\rangle$ corresponds to $(0,0,1)^T$ and after the rotation it becomes $(1,0,0)^T$, which is $| 1\rangle$, and the same can be done with $1/\sqrt2(| 0\rangle+i| 1\rangle)$, ignoring the global phase.