# How to derive the rotations caused by the H gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, bloch-sphere, hadamard

In Nielsen and Chuang, there's the following paragraph:

> The Hadamard operation is just a rotation of the sphere about the ˆy axis by 90◦, followed by a rotation about the ˆx axis by 180◦.

I am wondering how we were able to know that this is the transformation that the H gate creates? Is it implied from the matrix representation of the H gate? If so, how?

Comment: [This answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/how-to-visualize-hadamard-gate-as-x-z-x-decomposition/18032#18032) will be helpful.

Comment: Bloch Sphere is the visualization tool to see those rotations. https://javafxpert.github.io/grok-bloch/

Comment: see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16533/55 for the general case

Answer (score 3):

We start with definition of $Rx(\theta_x)$ and $Ry(\theta_y)$ rotations:
$$
Rx(\theta_x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta_x/2) & -i\sin(\theta_x/2)\\
-i\sin(\theta_x/2) & \cos(\theta_x/2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
Ry(\theta_y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta_y/2) & -\sin(\theta_y/2)\\
\sin(\theta_y/2) & \cos(\theta_y/2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Setting $\theta_x = \pi$ we have
$$
Rx(\pi)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i\\
-i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=-i
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=-iX,
$$
which is NOT gate ($X$), up to global phase represented by $-i$. However, the global phase can be neglected and we are left with $X$ gate.

If we put $\theta_y = \pi/2$ we get
$$
Ry(\pi/2)=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Multiplying $XRy(\pi/2)$ we get
$$
XRy(\pi/2)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
=H
$$

Comment: I think this should answers the OP question (+1). Also you probably meant to put $\theta_x$ instead of $\theta$ in your $R_X$ gate, similar with $R_Y$. Not a big deal but just thought I should mention it.

Comment: @KAJ226: Thanks, fixed.